# Why is $r'/r^2 = -1/r$?

Tags: homework-and-exercises, mathematics

If $r=r(t)$, why is $\frac{r'(t)}{(r(t))^2}$ = $\frac{1}{r(t)}$ where $'$ denotes the derivative? I saw it in a lecture.

Can you please explain?

Comment: You're missing a derivative on the right-hand-side of your equation. The equation you saw was likely $ \frac{r'(t)}{(r(t)^2)} = -  \left(\frac{1}{r(t)}\right)'$.

Answer (score 2):

It's not...not unless $r(t)$ happens to be $r_0e^{-t}$.

Answer (score 2):

It isn't true. What's true is that: $$\int \frac {r'(t)}{r^2(t)} dt = -\frac{1}{r(t)}$$

Comment: Thank you. But I am confused a bit - is there a similar relation maybe? Maybe I have a typo.

Comment: As @JLA said, that is a differential equation, that you may simply write as: $\frac{dr}{dt}=r$ and has unique solution $r=r_0 e^{-t}.$ If you could give some context maybe one could say where it comes from (if it is a typo).